# How can I change the UITypeEditor of a PropertyGrid element?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, uitypeeditor

I made myself an UITypeEditor which draws me the selected colors on the PropertyGrid. It looks like this:

[PropertyGrid after UITypeEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRjGh.png)

The PaintValue event was overwritten in the editor which draws me the rectangle with those colors:

```
Rectangle destRect = e.Bounds;
                LinearGradientBrush linGrBrush = Wire_Colors.GetWireLinearGradientBrush(Wire_Colors.GetWireColor(e.Value.ToString()), destRect);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(linGrBrush, destRect);
```

**To my Question:**

Is there a way to edit the UITypeEditor of the elements on the left side of the PropertyGrid?

Comment: What do you mean by "edit the UITypeEditor of the elements on the left side of the PropertyGrid"?

Comment: When looking at the image: I want to draw the colored rectangles besides the variables on the left instead of the contents on the right side.

Comment: UITypeEditor are only for values, not for label/description.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know that. Is is even possible to change the labels in the PropertyGrid in the first place?

An alternative I'm thinking of would be a DataTable / DataGridView where I would just use a colored cell instead.

Comment: Labels can be changed using [DisplayName("blah blah")] attribute on property definitions

Comment: Was was not thinking of the DisplayName, but placing those colored rectangles onto the labels.

Comment: You can't change the property grid look & feel (size, style, fonts, colors, keyboard behavior, shortcuts, etc.). It's very hardcoded. You can only play on value cells using UITypeEditor (and TypeConverter)

Comment: Thanks. So I will have to think of another solution. Clsoing this one then.

Comment: If a commercial option is an option for you, Smart PropertyGrid.Net is highly customizable and you can override many painted elements through drawing managers. Disclaimer: I'm the author of this component.

Comment: It is currently only for an internal project. But the Smart PropertyGrid sounds interesting. I will look into it in case I would need it in the future.